# Error: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

First off I know that other people have posted about this error but I believe my issue is different than the others. I have a method that I use to convert a string to datetime and I was trying to use the DateTime.TryParse method instead but I'm only getting the above error when I use the DateTime.TryParse method even though both results are exactly the same. I'm very confused about why this is happening.

```
My method:

public static DateTime parseDateTime(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            return Convert.ToDateTime(data.Replace('"', ' ').Trim());
        }
        catch (FormatException format)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(format.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
        catch (OverflowException overflow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(overflow.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }

        return DateTime.MaxValue;
    }
```

Returns:
{11/26/2014 12:00:00 AM}

```
My new method:

DateTime date = new DateTime();
 using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter amexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
{
DateTime.TryParse(lineArray[0], out date);
amexAdapter.Insert(symbol, open, high, low, close, volume, adjClose, date); // error here
}
```

Returns:
{12/26/2014 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: I don't see a `SqlDateTime` used here.

Comment: You can't get exception in title while using `DateTime.Parse`. Probably, you've shown not all code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to include the line that was throwing the exception. Very important I know @PatrickHofman

Comment: for strings from 'uncontrollable' sources always use DateTime.TryParse(), always use a format string like 'yyyy-MM-dd', always use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: What is `amexAdapter`, and what is the value for `date`?

Comment: @DrKoch I will try to edit my code to use that but why would my method work just fine and the seemingly better method doesn't?

Comment: You missed all the lines of code where you're filling `date`, not only line throwing the exception.

Comment: If you have that value for your date variable, then the error is not caused by an invalid value. Probably something inside the amexAdapter.Insert method is broken, but without that code ....

Comment: @PatrickHofman amexAdapter is a strongly typed sql dataadapter and the value for date is 12/26/2014 12:00:00 AM

Comment: You are getting the exception because here `DateTime.TryParse(lineArray[0], out date);` `lineArray[0]` is not getting parsed as a date so `date` is getting set to `DateTime.MinValue` which is `01/01/0001 00:00:00` which is outside of the range of dates that SQL can handle. You need to look at why `lineArray[0]` cannot be parsed.

Comment: I updated the code to show how I'm initiating everything

Comment: Did you set a break point there to see the real value of `date`?

Comment: SQL Server Equiv to .NET DateTime is DateTime2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
DateTime.TryParse(lineArray[0], out date);
```

When `lineArray[0]` is not recognised as a valid date, the `DateTime.TryParse` will return false and set the `date` to DateTime.MinValue. This is not a valid value for a sql `date` or `datetime` column.

The fact that you are "initializing" that `date` variable (`DateTime date = new DateTime();`) doesn't matter: the tryParse ignores that value and assigns a new one. You can remove that `=new DateTime()`.

And had it worked, then `new DateTime()` would still end up as DateTime.MinValue.

So you need to test the result of TryParse and do something else if it is false.